# If statement A requires B to be true, is it possible to prove A without using B?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

[it is totally described in the title in fact]

I have a statement A that is true **only if** statement B is true. 
Is it possible to prove A without referring to B in any way? (I mean, if you use something that implies B but you d, that's not the thing)

Example (geometric):

- given some info and that point M is the center of AB, you need to prove that some two angles are equal;
- you know that if M is not the center of AB, then the angles are not equal;
- is it possible to prove that the angles are equal without using the fact that M is the center of AB?

(just an example that led me to this question)

Comment: The congruence of two triangles requires congruence of each pair of corresponding angles. However, you can prove triangle congruence using only their sides.

Comment: Sure. (In fact you wouldn’t generally expect to use a consequence of something in a proof of it.) For instance, $A$ is true only if $A$ is true, but you certainly won’t be using that fact in the proof.

Comment: But looking at your example, this is not what you mean to be asking. You want to know if we have $B\to A$ and want to prove $B$ *under the assumption of $A,$* do we need to actually use the assumption of $A$ in the proof. If we don’t, then we just have a proof of $B$ outright, and thus since $B\to A,$ we have a proof of $A$ outright. So the answer is only if $A$ holds outright (i.e. it is a consequence of your other background assumptions).

Answer (score 1):

Logically "$A$ requires $B$" merely rules out the combination ($A$ true, $B$ untrue).

Suppose $A$ is "$n=2$" and $B$ is "$n$ is even". Clearly $A$ requires $B$, since if $n$ is odd it can't equal $2$. But we might have proved $n=2$ from, say

- $n$ is an integer such that $1<n<e$, or
- $n=\sum_{r=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{2^r})$,

or any number of ways not involving the concept of evenness.

If $A$ requires $B$ then proving $B$ false would disprove $A$—but this doesn't mean that a proof of $A$ must use $B$.

"$A$ requires $B$" and "Proving $A$ entails proving $B$" are different propositions.